# raspbian : execute a command each time ttyUSB0 comes up

Tags: arduino, raspbian

I have a raspbian with an USB connection to an arduino (/dev/ttyUSB0).
I would like, each times I replug (after unplug it), to run command, but I have no idea how to do this.
Reset the speed configuration and restart the program that use it.
Does someone known what to do ?

Comment: Write a script that monitors this path and do things correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are in any Linux represented as files. So you can make script in any language which in loop will be checking if the file with specific name exists (The name of port you looking for). If the file is detected than you can execute what you want.